# Joining two lists with nested lists

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

Trying to find a way to join two lists along with nested lists through LINQ or PLINQ.

I have `List A`, `List B` and wanted to join these two with their parent and child properties.

I have tried the following

```
List<data> result = A.Where(o=>foo.Any(x=>x.headerid=o.headerid)) &&
o.details.Any(y=>foo.Any(z=>z.headerid=o.headerid && z.detailid=y.detailid)).ToList();
```

But not sure this is the right way of doing it. Here the foo list is being scanned twice. I wanted to have a join query to fix this be it lambda or join query. Preferably join query.

```
class filterclass
{
   public string headerid;
   public string detailid;
}

class data 
{
  public string headerid;
  public string headername;
  public List<Detail> details;
  //...
}

class detail
{
  public string detailid;
  public string detailname;
  //...
}

List<data> A = new List<data>();
List<filterclass> foo = new List<filterclass>();
```

Now my need is to join A and foo with the fields like
`A.headerid = foo.headerid` and `A.detail.detailid = foo.detailid`.

Thing is `A.detail` is the nested list and I am not sure how to join it.  Not sure whether the `FirstOrDefault` or `All` will work in this case. Also don't want to loop

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

I need to have a LINQ JOIN query.

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve]. Also, use consistent names. The names you use currently are pretty confusing. What is `A`, `B`, `foo`? Also, it's relevant to know the origin of the data. It may make a big difference if they're from a SQL backend and queried by, for example, Entity Framework. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Hello Gert, Thanks for the reply. Its not something from SQL. Its a .net object. Also  A is a list as i mentioned above as like as the foo. I just need to join these two lists with my above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Concat Extension Method for joining lists:

```
var combinedList = list1.Concat(list2);
```

And for your specific example:

```
var combinedList = A.Concat(foo);
```

It creates an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` which will enumerate the elements of **list1** and **list2** in that order.